# Proof of Theorem Concerning Conway's "Nim Field"

Tags: fields, ordinal-numbers, surreal-numbers, characteristic-2

I have a question about the proof of theorem 44 in "On Numbers and Games" on page 58, concerning the "Nim field" ${ON}_2$. As background, ${ON}_2$ turns the ordinals into a field of characteristic 2 using a recursive construction of addition and multiplication, in which each is defined as the minimal element *not* in a certain set of 'excludents'. Conways uses ordinals to refer both to ordinal numbers in their capacity as elements of the field, and sets of such elements, so "$\Delta$ is a ring" means "the set of all ordinals smaller than $\Delta$ form a sub-ring of ${ON}_2$". Operations in ${ON}_2$ are referred to using ordinary addition and multiplication symbols, while normal ordinal arithmetic operations are enclosed in [brackets]. The theorem runs as follows(not an exact quote, edited for clarity):

> Let $\Delta$ be a ring that is not a field. Let $\Gamma$ be the largest additive subgroup all of whose non-zero elements have multiplicative inverses in $\Delta$. Then we have
> $$ \Delta^n \gamma_n + \Delta^{n-1} \gamma_{n-1} + \ldots + \Delta \gamma_1 + \delta = [\Delta(\Gamma^{n-1} \gamma_n + \ldots + \gamma_1) + \delta] $$

In the proof, crucial use is made of the following statement. The typical excludent of $\Delta^{n+1}$ has the form  $$\Delta^n(\delta_0 + \ldots + \delta_n) + \ldots + \delta_0\delta_1\ldots\delta_n$$

and Conway claims that each of the coefficients of this polynomial is of the form $\Gamma$ or $\Gamma + \gamma$ for some $\gamma \in \Gamma$. But I don't see why this should be the case. For we could take $\delta_1 = \delta_2 = \ldots = \delta_n = 0$, then the first coefficient is equal to $\delta_0$, an arbitrary element of $\Delta$, which does not have to be of this form. Conway mentions that the proof is incomplete and that you actually need that $\Gamma$ is a field. But I don't see (a) why this should be true, (b) if it was true, how it would repair the proof. Has anybody read this section and know what Conway was getting at? Perhaps the theorem or the proof is just wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the presentation of this material beginning on p. 439 of Aaron N. Siegel's "Combinatorial Game Theory", American Mathematical Society, 2013? Although it's been a while since I looked at it, I recall it being clearer than Conway's treatment.

Comment: Yes, I did. He doesn't cover this theorem.